# Jest Enzyme test error :Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have index.js file which contains:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {combineReducers,createStore,compose,applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import playerReducer from './store/Player/PlayerReducers'
import cardReducer from './store/Cards/cardsReducer'
import playersReducer from './store/Players/PlayersReducer'
import stylesReducer from './store/Styles/StylesReducer'
import gameReducer from './store/Game/gameReducer'
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    player: playerReducer,
    cards:cardReducer,
    players:playersReducer,
    styles:stylesReducer,
    game:gameReducer
})
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
     <HashRouter >
      <App />
     </HashRouter>
</Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();

export default store
```

and I have App.js file which contains:

```js
import React, { PureComponent, Suspense } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import './App.css'
import SignUp from './Register/SignUp'
import SignIn from './Register/SignIn'
import * as stylesActions from './store/Styles/StylesActions'
import Entrance from './components/Entrance/Entrance'
import Profile from './components/Profile/Profile'
import NotFound from './UI/NotFound/NotFound'
import Fallback from './UI/Fallback/Fallback'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
const Lobby = React.lazy(() => import("./Lobby/Lobby"))
const Game = React.lazy(() => import('./containers/Game/Game'))


class App extends PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App"
        data-test="App-component"
        >
         <Switch>
         <Route path="/" exact render={() => (
        <Suspense fallback={
      <Fallback />
      }>
          <Entrance />
        </Suspense>
      )} />
    <Route  path="/auth/signup" exact  component={SignUp}/>
      <Route  path="/auth/signin" exact  component={SignIn}/> 
      <Route  path="/lobby" exact render={() => (
        <Suspense fallback={
      <Fallback />
      }>
          <Lobby />
        </Suspense>
      )}/>
      <Route  path="/profile" exact component={Profile}/>
      <Route path="/game" exact render={() => (
        <Suspense fallback={
      <Fallback />
      }>
          <Game />
        </Suspense>
      )} />
      <Route  component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>

        </div>
)
}
}



const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onChangeMusicStatus:(arg) => dispatch(stylesActions.musicPaused(arg))

  }
  }
  
  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
  player: state.player,
  styles:state.styles,
  players:state.players
      }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

when I try to test it gives me this error

> Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a  or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what version of react-redux are you using, can you post your test, if you are using a react-redux 7 you must wrap your text component with Provider:

```
const TestComponent = <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>
your test code here...
```

also you can export only the `App` component (not the connected) and test it separately.

Comment: yeah version is 7.2.0. But I didn't get what you mean. I test it in another file. Why should I wrap it?

Comment: this is how react-redux 7 works... according to their documentation https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests you should wrap it with <Provider> : "If you want to test its interaction with Redux, this is good news: you can wrap it in a <Provider> with a store created specifically for this unit test. But sometimes you want to test just the rendering of the component, without a Redux store."